# Rmarkdown import latest webcam image?

Tags: r, r-markdown, learnr

I'm writing a learnr::tutorial markdown for my students, and would like one of the slides to show the latest image from the webcam on Palmer Station, Antarctica:

https://www.usap.gov/videoclipsandmaps/palwebcam.cfm

However, the field doesn't register as an image - likely because it is some sort of gallery?

I cannot use the page link, the image adress, or the image to insert into:

```
![](https://www.usap.gov/videoclipsandmaps/SouthPoleWebcam/Pal00095.jpg?=92056851.6281)
```

Many thanks if there is anyone who knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
{r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=12}
knitr::include_app("https://www.usap.gov/videoclipsandmaps/SouthPoleWebcam/Pal00095.jpg?=92056851.6281")
```

If you render the html in the Viewer pane, be sure to pop out to web browser to see the iFrame.

Comment: Great solution @Susan! Is there a way to resize it to 100% of the browser width?

Comment: @Silviculturalist Yes you can add fig.width and you can adjust fig.height. in the chunk, for instance: {r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=12, fig.height = 12}